# Retrieving content from a bean without having to worry about returning a null?

Tags: java

Suppose you have some content that is guaranteed to have some value. Your job is to find it when given something `like` it.

**This works:**

```
public KVPair getKvpForKey(String keyValue) {
    KVPair kvpInThisContent = null;

    for (KVPair kvp : kvContent) {
        if (kvp.getKey().getAsFound().equals(keyValue)) {
            kvpInThisContent =  kvp;
            break;
        }
    }

    return kvpInThisContent;
}
```

**This also works:**

```
public KVPair getKvpForKey(String keyValue) {

    for (KVPair kvp : kvContent) {
        if (kvp.getKey().getAsFound().equals(keyValue)) 
            return kvp;
    }

    return null;
}
```

But ... both assume a possibility .. that in some cases `null` may be returned. While fine, this seems sloppy, assuming we know that it is not possible (content is there!).

Is there a way to do it cleaner without having to worry about a `null`?

Comment: You can either return `null` or throw an exception or `assert false` if you're sure that the algorithm will never get past the loop.

Comment: Right. No way to avoid it? This condition basically is impossible, it will never happen. Both null or exception seem wasteful

Comment: There are no guarantees as far as the compiler is concerned ;)

Comment: One additional question I would have for you though is how are you guaranteeing that the keyValue supplied to the method is not invalid? There is nothing from your code snippet that would require this? COuldn't the user of your method pass in null for instance?

Comment: @alex: You can just put that into the contract: "keyValue must not be null" and be done with it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know about your invariants, so you *have* to put a `return` statement at the end. What you can do, however, is add an `assert false` statement to make it clear that this is not intended to ever run:

```
assert false;
return null;
```

The additional bonus is that you'll get an exception thrown in your face if your assumption is wrong and you run it with `-ea`.

Also remember to state in your specification that the function will not return `null`! That way the caller doesn't have to worry about it and can avoid an additional check.